# What is the better approach to dealing with data and UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I want to understand the right approach in building my app's architecture. I have read a lot. And I'm facing with **two** different approaches. Moreover the popularity of each kind of approach it seems are fifty-fifty.

**The first one** - config cell with data in ViewController or TableViewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.title.text = "Some text"
    // config other data...

    return cell
}
```

**The second one** - config cell with via protocol

```
protocol SomeCellProtocol {
    func setTitle(text: String)
}

class SomeCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!    
}

extension SomeCell: SomeCellProtocol {

    func setTitle(text: String) {
        title.text = text
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.setTitle(text: "Some text")
    // config other data...

}
```

So the questions are:

- What is the better approach, or both cases is ok?
- It is considered that we passing data to view in the **The second one** approach?
- Am I right that in case **one** we have passive view, but in case **second** not?

Comment: From my personal observations, sometimes you need to do if-else in `cellForRowAt` method and create different cells, each cell might have different UI components and might be depending on different dataSources to hook up with. So in some cases `cellForRowAt` method might get too messy. Second approach might help to keep `cellForRowAt` method tidier.

Comment: I would definitely say that your second approach is much more useful. Why? in that case you could even add generics to configure, not only one cell, but different ones as well. The delegate function for example can be used to configure the entire UI of the cell with viewModels if you do something like `configureCell(with: SomeViewModel)`. And as @emrepun mentioned, your `cellForRow` method will be much cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: @RomanRomanenko, I would say yes to both questions. 2) you will always pass some sort of data to the view, no matter the architecture. The difference is how your view uses the data to get configured, does it take a model and configures itself? or does the controller configures its views. Which brings us to the 3rd question, which I will say is also yes, it is passive because the controller configures the entire view, so the cell is just in charge of displaying the data, but not configuring itself. Hope it's clear

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

They both work the same, but the slight advantage in the `protocol`,

1- Reuse for other cells.

2- Tidier `cellForRowAt` over all.

3- Slightly faster in the future as you speak to the functions directly instead of accessing the `@IBOutlets` and edit it directly which leads to minimum mistake percentage as you are limited to the `protocol`.

4- you can use it without having to create the cells at all and this is good when you want to just create everything really fast in the `UIViewController` then create the custom cells.

**Question 2:** 
Passing data to the cell is great for clean code, as you can create as much as polymorphic functions to handle data right into the cell instead of manually `if else` it inside the `func cellForRowAt`.

For example:

```
protocol configurable {
 func configure(dataForm: SomeObject)
 func configure(dataForm: SomeOtherObject)
}
```

**Question 3:**

> Passive View. A screen and components with all application specific behavior extracted into a controller so that the widgets have their state controlled entirely by controller.

They both are passive.

Answer (score 1):

regarding question 2:

I believe that we can improve the version "config cell with via protocol" if we move on to the protocol instead of the object being transferred.

```
protocol DataForCellProtocol {
   func getTitle()->String?
   func getDescription()->String?
   ...
}
```

Then we create the `CellConfigureProtocol` using the `DataFromCellProtocol`:

```
protocol CellConfigureProtocol{
     func configureCell(with obj: DataForCellProtocol)
}
```

Now to build a cell for any data you just need to implement a `DataForCellProtocol` for them. And now we can be sure that we have passive view.